# Empty Input line raises an error in Python 3.3

Tags: python-3.3

I'm new at Python and trying some exercises I found on-line. The one I'm busy with requires an text input first, folowed by an ineteger input.
I get stuck on the integer input which raises an error.
I've started by modifying the code slightly to test myself when I first got the error.
Eventually changed it backed to be exactly like the example/exercise had it, but both resulted in the same error, on the same line.
The error raised was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ************************ line 7, in <module>
    numOfGuests = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I've checked around a bit and found it get's triggered when the input is empty, but according to what I've read the the rest of the code should handle that.

```
numOfGuests = int(input())
if numOfGuests:
```

I expected the code to ask for the input again if nothing was entered, but get the error instead.
Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I've managed to figure out a work-around, and even though it isn't a answer to my question, I'll take it.
For anyone that's interested, here's what I did:
I changed:

```
numOfGuests=int(input())
```

to:

```
numOfGuests=input()
```

Only once something was entered did I convert it:

```
numOfGuests=int(numOfGuests)
```

so the final block is:

```
numOfGuests=''
while not numOfGuests:
    print('How many guests will you have?')
    numOfGuests = input()
numOfGuests=int(numOfGuests)
```

Any ideas to improve it, or some insight, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is 10 months old but I just want to share the reason why you are having an error *ValueError*.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ************************ line 7, in <module>
    numOfGuests = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Is because the [**input()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function reads any value and convert it into a string type. Even if you try to input empty or blank.

### Sample code:

```
any_input = input("Input something: ")
print(f"Your input is: [{any_input}]")
```

Ouput:

```
Input something: 
Your input is: []
```

Then the blank or empty string will be passed inside the [**int()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) function. The int() function will try convert string into an integer with a base of 10. As we all know, there is no blank or empty numbers. That is why it is giving you a *ValueError*.

To avoid this, we need to use try-except/[EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) in your code:

```
try:
    # Try to convert input to integer
    numOfGuests = int(input("How many guests will you have? "))
except:
    # Handle Value Error
```

And put inside a While-loop to repeat until input is valid.

### Sample code:

```
while True:
    try:
        # Try to convert input to integer
        numOfGuests = int(input("How many guests will you have? "))
        # If input is valid go to next line
        break # End loop
    except:
        # Handle Value Error
        print("Invalid input!")
print(f"The number of guest/s is: {numOfGuests}")
```

Ouput:

```
How many guest will you have? 3
The number of guest/s is: 3
```